# SQL - Child table records pivot with parents - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, string-aggregation

I have parent & child table like below for Oracle.

Have to display the child records separated with a comma.

T_OPT_PARENT

```
OPT | OPT_DESC| STATUS 
XY  | XY_DESC | A 
YZ  | YZ_DESC | A 
ZZ  | ZZ_DESC | A
```

T_OPT_CHILD

```
OPT | CODE
XY  | ONE_CODE
XY  | TWO_CODE
XY  | THREE_CODE
ZZ  | ONE_CODE
ZZ  | TWO_CODE
```

**Expected output**

```
OPT | OPT_DESC| CODE                         | STATUS 
XY  | XY_DESC | ONE_CODE,TWO_CODE,THREE_CODE | A
YZ  | YZ_DESC |                              | A 
ZZ  | ZZ_DESC | ONE_CODE, TWO_CODE           | A
```

Could some one help me to construct a SQL query to obtain the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Answer:

```
SELECT A.OPT,A.OPT_DESC,D.List AS CODE,A.STATUS FROM T_OPT_PARENT A
LEFT JOIN(
select OPT,
  listagg(CODE, ',') 
    within group (order by OPT) as list 
from T_OPT_CHILD
group by OPT)D ON A.OPT=D.OPT
ORDER BY A.OPT
```

Check the answer in SQL Fiddle:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed314c/6)